# Where does the ssh client in git bash store it's known_hosts file on windows?

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash

I'm running a git bash on windows 7, and would like to remove a few hosts from the known_hosts file.

I can't seem to find a .ssh directory anywhere. Where does the ssh client included with git bash store it's known hosts, on Windows 7?

Comment: To remove host from known_hosts you need just execute command "ssh-keygen.exe -R host.name.here"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Git Bash stores the known hosts in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` ;-)

Wherever that file really is. When you are in Git Bash, you can edit the file with `vim ~/.ssh/known_hosts` for example.

--

(by default ~ is at /c/Users/[user_name] so `/c/Users/[user_name]/.ssh/known_hosts`)

Comment: In my case it seems Git Bash doesn't use this file, while IntelliJ does use it.

I used the command `git remote rename a b`

Answer (score 25):

On my Windows PC it stored it in

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh`

Answer (score 2):

On my PC it can be found on another drive ( not on default C:/ )

`H:\.ssh`

Comment: Can you change the drive? How? This is driving me mad :(

Answer (score 0):

I find mine in

```
C:\Windows\System32\.ssh
```

Though I wish I could set it to be

```
C:\Users\[username]\.ssh
```

as it is in other instances.